# Include apostrophe with .split()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display an array of words from a user's post. However the method I'm using treats an apostrophe like whitespace.

```
<%= var = Post.pluck(:body) %>
<%= var.join.downcase.split(/\W+/) %>
```

So if the input text was: `The baby's foot`
it would output `the` `baby` `s` `foot`,
but it should be `the` `baby's` `foot`.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Which method is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "treats an apostrophe like whitespace"?

Comment: "apostrophe as such"--What does "such" refer to?

Comment: So I'm plucking data. <%= var = Post.pluck(:body) %>
<%= var.join.downcase.split(/\W+/) %>

I just want the apostrophe to be included in the returned words. So it would say "baby's" instead of "baby" "s"

Comment: Be very careful with `\w` or `\W` unless you know exactly what you're going to get when dealing with that character-class.

Comment: And, BTW, you're getting down votes and close votes most likely because you don't show any effort toward solving the problem. We'd really like evidence of your research and why searching didn't reveal the answer before asking. Your question is very elementary and easily resolved by reading regular expression tutorials and/or searching. See "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below RegEx instead of `/\W+/`

```
var.join.downcase.split(/[^'\w]+/)
```

`/\W/` refers to all non-word characters, apostrophe is one such non-word character.
To keep the code as close to original intent, we can use `/[^'\w]/` - this means that all characters that are not apostrophe and word character.

Comment: Perfect! That fixed everything. Thanks for the explanation too!

Comment: Please see my answer below, this approach is too naïve.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is too naïve:

```
▶ "It’s naïve approach".split(/[^'\w]+/)
#⇒ [
#  [0] "It",
#  [1] "s",
#  [2] "nai",
#  [3] "ve",
#  [4] "approach"
# ]
```

this is because nowadays there is almost 2016 and many users might want to use their normal names, like, you know, José Østergaard. Punctuation is not only the apostroph, as you might notice.

```
▶ "It’s naïve approach".split(/[^'’\p{L}\p{M}]+/)
#⇒ [
#  [0] "It’s",
#  [1] "naïve",
#  [2] "approach"
# ]
```

Further reading: [Character Properties](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Character+Properties).

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of mudasobwa's answer, here's what `\w` and `\W` bring to the party:

```
chars = [*' ' .. "\x7e"].join
# => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

That's the usual visible lower-ASCII characters we'd see in code. See [the Regexp documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) for more information.

Grabbing the characters that match `\w` returns:

```
chars.scan(/\w+/)
# => ["0123456789",
#     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
#     "_",
#     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]
```

Conversely, grabbing the characters that don't match `\w`, or that match `\W`:

```
chars.scan(/\W+/)
# => [" !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./", ":;<=>?@", "[\\]^", "`", "{|}~"]
```

`\w` is defined as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` which is not what you want to normally call "word" characters. Instead they're typically the characters we use to define variable names.

If you're dealing with only lower-ASCII characters, use the character-class

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

For instance:

```
chars = [*' ' .. "\x7e"].join
lower_ascii_chars = '[a-zA-Z]'
not_lower_ascii_chars = '[^a-zA-Z]'
chars.scan(/#{lower_ascii_chars}+/)
# => ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]
chars.scan(/#{not_lower_ascii_chars}+/)
# => [" !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@", "[\\]^_`", "{|}~"]
```

Instead of defining your own, you can take advantage of the POSIX definitions and [character properties](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties):

```
chars.scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/)
# => ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]

chars.scan(/\p{Alpha}+/)
# => ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]
```

Regular expressions always seem like a wonderful new wand to wave when extracting information from a string, but, like [the Sorcerer's Apprentice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice_(2010_film)) found out, they can create havoc when misused or not understood.

Knowing this should help you write a bit more intelligent patterns. Apply that to what the documentation shows and you should be able to easily figure out a pattern that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Running that string through `irb` with the same `split` call that you wrote in your comment gets this:

```
irb(main):008:0> "The baby's foot".split(/\W+/)
=> ["The", "baby", "s", "foot"]
```

However, if you use `split` without an explicit delimiter, you get the split you're looking for:

```
irb(main):009:0> "The baby's foot".split
=> ["The", "baby's", "foot"]
```

Does that get you what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! It does answer the apostrophe problem. However, now when it plucks the data, it connects the last word of the first post and the first word of the second post such as "foot.Whale" instead of keeping those two separate (being two separate posts). Do you have another answer that's also staring me right in the face?